# Telerik RadScheduler and appointment attributes

Tags: telerik-scheduler

I've got an aspx page, and in the code behind, I'm building a list of Telerik.Web.UI.Appointment objects, and setting the datasource of the RadScheduler to that list.

For each appointment object I'm adding several attributes to it.  Things like CusomerID.

```
appt.Attributes.Add("CustomerID", 23);
```

I need to get at this information client side.  From the documentation, it appears to me that this should work, but it does not.

```
var appt = eventArgs.get_appointment();
var list = appt.get_attributes();
var attr = list.getAttribute('CustomerID');
```

When I run this, attr is always undefined.

So, what is my problem?  Am I not adding the attributes in the correct way on the server side, or is something messed up with my client side call?

Answer (score 1):

Add CustomAttributeNames="CustomerID" to your  tag in the aspx. Otherwise get_attributes() just returns nothing if I recall correctly.